# MongoDB "select x from y where id in" another table

Tags: mongodb-3.0

I'm trying to understand how can I achieve this in MongoDB:

```
select *
from Table1
where id in
(selct id from table2)
```

I'm trying to aggregate but I just can't understand how JSON works:

```
db.Collection1.find
    (
            {"Field_from_Collection1":
                {$nin:db.Collection2.distinct("The_Field_I_want_to_compare")
                    
                }
                
            }
    ).limit(1)
```

I need to find all information from collection1, but only if the ID is in collection2.

The reason I'm doing this is that I need to find the documents in Collection1, that has specifics IDS, and it's 600k IDS to look for.

as a SQL Server DBA, I'm really struggling to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$lookup` for subquery.

Check out the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

There is an example from the document.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to only get the entries from `collection1` which are matched in `collection2` without any information from `collection2` attached, you can use:

```
db.getCollection('collection1').aggregate([
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'collection2',
       localField: 'coll2_id',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'coll2_data'
     }
},
{ "$unwind": "$coll2_data" },
{ "$project": {
    "coll2_data": false
    }
}
])
```

- this first makes a left-outer join and adds the information from `collection2` to all `collection1` entries into the field `coll2_data`.
- as we only expect exactly one `collection2` match for `collection1.coll2_id` we `unwind` the array to a single object. This also filters all `collection1` entries which do not have a match in `collection2`
- lastly the `project` removes the `collection2` data from the joined entries